# Relay client for existing working graphQL server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I have working [tinySQL GraphQL server](https://github.com/javascriptiscoolpl/graphQL-tinySQL) running at 127.0.0.1:3000. I would like to create **any working** Relay client for it. I mean any working example for query:

```
{
  groupBy (age: 20, job: "student") {
    id,
    name,
    age,
    job
  }
}
```

that will output in React component something like that:

```
{
  "data": {
    "groupBy": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Marie",
        "age": 20,
        "job": "student"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Jessie",
        "age": 20,
        "job": "student"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Most important thing is I want to be able to set GraphQL host IP and port and also don't want to change anything in GraphQL server code. Is it possible to do it? Is it possible to do it without babelRelayPlugin.js, babel-relay-plugin, webpack, webpack-dev-server or any other magic tricks?

EDIT:

I mean:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      // Simple example here?
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
);

const AppContainer = Relay.createContainer(App, {
  // Simple example here?
});

ReactDOM.render(
  // Simple example here?
);
```

Anyone? Is it possible to do it like this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that is not possible with Relay. You not only need to use Relay's babel plugins, but your server also has to match the Relay GraphQL spec.

However, there are alternatives to Relay that require much less boilerplate, such as [Apollo Client](https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client) or [Lokka](https://github.com/kadirahq/lokka). If you're looking for good React integration, then Apollo Client is probably the right choice for what you describe.

Full disclosure: I am a contributor to Apollo Client

Comment: I know that JSX need to be translated, also the QL syntax need to be translated and there is no solution for that to run source like "node index.js". I can run or import babel-relay-plugin and even make working config  in webpack.config.js but I know there are some problems with viewer, root queries and even routing (ok maybe I had problem with it and nobody else :-)) so I am looking for WORKING SIMPLE implementation for Relay.createContainer and Routing if needed. The Relay.injectNetworkLayer works fine but maybe there is better solution?

Comment: However, I really like the simple usage of Lokka. Relay should be like this.

Comment: Anyone else? really impossible? I make some research in the playground here https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#/ and I replaced "hello" field name everywhere with "text" and this stopped working !!! Looks like Relay depends on schema field names !!! This is horrible and totally unacceptable !!!

Comment: Have you tried apollo client? The `gql` syntax doesn't need to be translated, it's a standard part of JavaScript, and you don't need to use React with it. I think it will do _exactly_ what you are looking for if you give it a try. Start with the core API: http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/core.html

Comment: Not yet but I will for sure. I wanted to get to work the Relay first.