# Relay Playground - how get it to work?

Tags: javascript, relayjs

I changed ("hello" to "text" in schema) in the [Relay Playground](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#/)  like this:

SCHEMA:

```
import {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt
} from 'graphql';

const GREETINGS = 
  {text: 'Hello world 1'}
;

const GreetingsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Greetings',
  fields: () => ({
    text: {type: GraphQLString}
  })
});

export default new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
      greetings: {
        type: GreetingsType,
        resolve: () => GREETINGS
      }
    })
  })
});
```

CODE:

```
class HelloApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {hello} = this.props.greetings;
    return <h1>test: {hello}</h1>;
  }
}

HelloApp = Relay.createContainer(HelloApp, {
  fragments: {
    greetings: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Greetings {
        text
      }
    `,
  }
});

class HelloRoute extends Relay.Route {
  static routeName = 'Hello';
  static queries = {
    greetings: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      query GreetingsQuery {
        greetings {
          ${Component.getFragment('greetings')},
        },
      }
    `,
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Relay.RootContainer Component={HelloApp} route={new HelloRoute()} />,
  mountNode
);
```

But it doesn't work and I get no error messages. Nothing is rendering. When I change the "text" back into "hello" back it works again. Why? Looks like the schema is hardcoded?

EDIT:

This works (I know why):

```
const sm = this.props.greetings;
return <h1>test: {sm.text}</h1>;
```

This works too:

```
const {text} = this.props.greetings;
return <h1>test: {text}</h1>;
```

but this below not works (and I don't know why if the one above works, why not works with custom variable name? what is specific with "text" variable name above?):

```
const {sm} = this.props.greetings;
return <h1>test: {sm}</h1>;
```

SOLVED:

ES6 feature. The curly braces should contain property. This is why `text` works. Thanks @Vince Ning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your React app, you are destructuring you your props like so:

```
const {hello} = this.props.greetings;
```

Since greetings is a JSON object, you only retrieved the hello property of that object, not the rest of it. In order to get correct data, you can either get the entire object by removing the {} around hello in that statement:

```
const hello = this.props.greetings;
console.log(hello.text); // Hello world 1
```

Or you can change the hello inside the {} to text to retrieve that specific property like so:

```
const {text} = this.props.greetings;
console.log(text); // Hello world 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work but I don't know why it works. See edit.

Comment: In JS ECMAScript 6, there's a technique called destructuring (http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) where if you put the curly braces around a variable, it automatically takes out the property of the object being assigned in the declaration. For example, if you had an object like `obj = {first: 1, second 2:}`, you could grab out the the properties `first` and `second` like so `const {first, second} = obj;` and you can directly access `first` and `second` within your code later where `// first == 1` and `second == 2`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I make edit, so why if I define `sm` like `var sm = {text:""}` still not works?

Comment: Because sm is not a property of this.props.greetings object

Comment: So there is chance I get this one [relay client for existing working graphql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688952/relay-client-for-existing-working-graphql-server) to work someday.

Comment: Awesome! And taking a look at your code in your other question, I don't think that's possible without those tools that you mentioned, and to have the data returned like that unless you define a return type of your mutation to include those fields. If you're looking for a GraphQL server that corresponds to the GraphQL spec right out of the box, you should check out something a buddy and I wrote called [Scaphold.io](https://scaphold.io) and you won't have to deal with any of that stuff when setting up your GraphQL server.